# How data should be visible to user and their sub-user using spring websocket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I want to achieve this functionality using sockjs + stomp + spring-boot-websocket as mentioned in image:

[image: Actually i want to achieve this functionality using sockjs + stomp + spring-boot-websocket as mentioned in image]

Comment: You should read some of the introductory texts to the [SO] site, such as [ask]. We are not a free code writing service. You need to show us more.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
1. Create utility that send message to user and inside you will need to send message to 3 users(User + Sub user) and use this utility inside your controller

2. Create dedicated channels that every user and sub user will subscribe into it. You can add security inside the subscribe message if you would like to.

Look below:

```
MyClassInterceptor  extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyClassInterceptor .class);
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
SimpMessageType type = (SimpMessageType) headers.get("simpMessageType");
String simpSessionId = (String) headers.get("simpSessionId");

if (type == SimpMessageType.CONNECT) {
    Principal principal = (Principal) headers.get("simpUser");
    LOGGER.debug("WsSession " + simpSessionId + " is connected for user " + principal.getName());
} else if (type == SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT) {
    LOGGER.debug("WsSession " + simpSessionId + " is disconnected");
}
return message;
}
}
```

Personally i think option one is simplier and doesn't require from you to deal with to many things.

You cannot do it with spring because it create prefix for every user according to user name so every username will have specific queue